# Inequality $\sqrt[4]{x^TA^{-2}x}\sqrt{x^TAx}\leq 1$ for symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a unit vector and $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Prove that
$$\sqrt[4]{x^TA^{-2}x}\sqrt{x^TAx}\leq 1.$$

#### Progress

Since A is spd, it is diagonalizable.   I proved that  $$\sqrt[4]{x^TA^{-2}x}\sqrt{x^TAx}\leq \sqrt{\kappa(A)},$$ where $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$. But I guess that  $\sqrt[4]{x^TA^{-2}x}\sqrt{x^TAx}\leq 1$ should hold.

Comment: Yes, since A is spd, it is diagonalizable.

 This is a problem someone gave to me. I proved that 
$$\sqrt[4]{x^TA^{-2}x}\sqrt{x^TAx}\leq \sqrt{\kappa(A)},$$
where $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$. But I guess that 
$$\sqrt[4]{x^TA^{-2}x}\sqrt{x^TAx}\leq 1.$$

Comment: It is absolutely correct. Of course, I found a similar example as follows:

$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
4 &  1\\ 
1 & 4
\end{array}\right]$
and $x=\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\ 
0
\end{array}\right]$

I wanted to say this example, but you mentioned it faster than I. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is false. Take $A$ to be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries= $1$ and $0.5$, and $x=(1,1)$

Answer (score 2):

> The problem probably had a typo, where the sign of the inequality got reversed.

There is some orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $UAU^T=D$ is diagonal, and therefore $UA^{-1}U^T=D^{-1}$, and $UA^{-2}U^T=D^{-2}$. Let us put $y:=Ux$. Then $x=U^Ty$, and the left-hand side of the inequality becomes

$$\sqrt[4]{(U^Ty)^TA^{-2}U^Ty}\sqrt{(U^Ty)^TAU^Ty}=\sqrt[4]{y^tUA^{-2}U^Ty}\sqrt{y^TUAU^Ty}=\sqrt[4]{y^TD^{-2}y}\sqrt{y^TDy}$$

If $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$ are the entries of the diagonal of $D$ (for which we know $d_i>0$) then this expression becomes
$$\sqrt[4]{\sum_i d_i^{-2}y_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_i d_iy_i^2}$$

> Notice that $\sum y_i^2=1$. Recall the [generalized mean inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) $M_p(\{x_i\})\leq M_q(\{x_i\})$, when $p\leq q$, where $M_p(\{x_i\})=\left(\sum w_i x_i^p\right)^{1/p}$, $x_i\geq0$, and $\sum w_i=1$.

We apply this inequality for $w_i=y_i^2$, $x_i=|d_i|^{-1/2}$, and $p=-4$ and $q=2$.

We get $$\left(\sum d_{i}^{-2}y_i^2\right)^{-1/4}=M_{-4}(\{|d_i|^{1/2}\})\leq M_{2}(\{|d_i|^{1/2}\})=\left(\sum d_i y_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$

From where $$1\leq\sqrt[4]{\sum d_i^{-2}y_i^2}\sqrt{\sum d_iy_i^2}$$

Therefore the reverse inequality is true.

Incidentally, combining with the inequality you have (which I haven't checked but I will  assume it is OK) with the condition number, this gives a bound from below for the condition number of symmetric positive definite matrices (although there are better bounds).